# How to adapt the width of an <input> automatically with the length(size) of the contained label in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a css issue. I have an input which can be filled automatically with a name of pdf document after clicking on upload button. The problem is maybe in some cases the size of the name of this pdf could be very long. **So My aim is to find a css trick on how to adapt the length of this `<input>` automatically with the containing label.**

a sample of code:

```
<input id="name" style="    margin-left: 83px;"
            placeholder="#{label['lbl.common.fileName']}"
            value="#{modelController.document.nameDoc}" />
```

Please this screen shot can explain more the problem.

[size-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EH3t.jpg)

Any Idea is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried overflow on the input field?

Comment: Please share the code which you've tried

Comment: Could you please share your code here...

Comment: I updated the question already

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a dynamic input field where the width will change size due to the contents inputted (uploaded PDF). You will need some JS for this to run. Like so:

```
 <input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions seem reasonable:

1. Instead of setting the width dynamically just make the input fill all the available space, e.g.:

   ```
   <form style="display:grid; grid-template-columns:200px auto">
     <input type="file"><input type="text">
   </form>
   ```

   This way it won't scale yet it wont matter either because it would fill all the remaining space except the 200px left for file selection input.
2. If you really need input changing size, you may consider using `contenteditable` ([MDN for the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)) instead of `<input>`. E.g.:

   ```
   <span contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid #000">file name here</span>
   ```

   It would behave exactly like a normal `<span>` (or whatever tag you use instead) except user would be able to edit its content. Keep in mind though that user may be able to paste formated text into it this way, so you may end with things like bold or italic if the text is copy-pasted from somewhere it was formated as such.

   Also remember to read the value via JavaScript prior sending the form as `contenteditable` does not make a form field itself.